# Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Failed to collect certificates

Tags: flutter, dart

He creado mi aplicación flutter, he creado una simple pantalla donde muestro un text, un appbar y un menú drawer, no he añadido ningún package adicional; y cuando trato de ejecutar la app en mi dispositivo físico, me dice que falla (***Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Failed to collect certificates***), que podría hacer???, la únicas soluciones que encuentro es hacer flutter clean y ejecutar nuevamente. adjunto imagen del error y flutter doctor
[image: Error generado en la consola]

[image: Flutter doctor]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Mi pregunta es como poder solucionar el error INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES, sale, cómo se ve en la imagen al ejecutar el proyecto en visual studio code

Answer (score 0):

Intentaste los siguientes pasos:

- Desinstalar la aplicación
- Ejecutar un clean project
- Ejecutar un build project
- Instalar la aplicación nuevamente

Comment: eso es lo que dicen todos los pots que he encontrado, al ejecutar borra la app, y si, ya he hecho todos los pasos :(